# jQuery top error with position()

Tags: jquery

I've done some research on this, but I'm unable to find anything that is to my need.

I'm getting the error:  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" in chrome but its says its coming from jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cp = $(".cp");
    var cppos = cp.position();
    var cpleft = cppos.left;
    cp.append('<div class="under-slider"></div>');

    $(".nav-item").hover(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var pos = $(this).position();
            var posLeft = pos.left;
            var td = posLeft - cpleft;
            $(".under-slider").animate({left:td}, 200);
            var cp = $(this);
        }, 100);
    }, function() {     
    });
});
```

Comment: `this` inside setTimeout anonymous function is refering to global window object, not to element `.nav-item`. Consider to use a closure or provide context of anonymous function

Comment: What number of line, where you got error?

Comment: you sure you didnt mean 'left' instead of top ? you dont use top anywhere in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see it, you could use `delay` instead:

```
$(".nav-item").hover(function () {   
        var pos = $(this).position();
        var posLeft = pos.left;
        var td = posLeft - cpleft;
        $(".under-slider").stop().delay(100).animate({  //stop() or not, depending behaviour you want
            left: td
        }, 200);   
}, function () {

});
```

Now regarding your issue, `this` inside anonymous function callback of timeout wasn't what you think it should be but refers to `window` object.

Basically, you could have use a variable closure, as:

```
$(".nav-item").hover(function() {
    var $elem = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        var pos = $elem.position();
        var posLeft = pos.left;
        var td = posLeft - cpleft;
        $(".under-slider").animate({left:td}, 200);
    }, 100);
}, function() {

});
```

Or proxify/bind context:

```
$(".nav-item").hover(function() {
    setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        var pos = $(this).position();
        var posLeft = pos.left;
        var td = posLeft - cpleft;
        $(".under-slider").animate({left:td}, 200);
        var cp = $(this);
    }, this), 100);
}, function() {

});
```